# Помогите исправить ошибку в методе при нахождении самого длинного слова в строке

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Словом считается слово, состоящее только из букв, не содержащее в себе цифры и спецсимволы. Я строку разделил на массив слов по пробелу используя `split()`. Потом считаю нулевой элемент максимальным и через цикл сравниваю остальные, но если первое слово в строке начинается с цифры или спецсимвола, то оно считается как слово, а не должно. Как мне это исправить, подскажите ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "3There 7has !been     9divided abs-      on98 then issue, with 578934 784,   +moderates5789 9concerned @about then on: then most vulnerable.";
    System.out.println(maxWord(str));
}

private static boolean isValidWord(String word) {
    char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
    for (char c : chars) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(c)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return !word.trim().isEmpty();
}

public static String maxWord(String input) {
    String[] words = input.split("\\s+");

    String max = words[0];
    for (String word : words) {
        if (isValidWord(word) && word.length() > max.length()) {
            max = word;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Вместо `String max = words[0];` попробуйте использовать инициализацию пустой строкой `String max = ""`.

Comment: Alex Chermenin, не проходит проверку. Сам метод я написал не правильно. Надо как-то по другому находить самое длинное слово.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы написали следующий код:

```
String[] words = input.split("\\s+");
String max = words[0];
```

Проблема в том, что `words[0]` не проверяется функцией `isValidWord()`!
Исправить можно разными способами:
 - использовать совет от ***Alex Chermenin*** насчет инициализации пустой строкой
 - предварительно отфильтровать массив words[], исключив из него "неправильные"
 слова

А вообще, я бы посоветовал использовать [регулярные выражения](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) в данном случае более полно, чтобы не изобретать велосипед. Благо, что регулярка для разделения слов получается в данном случае очень простая - разделителями будут все символы, не являющиеся буквами.
Примерно так:

```
String[] words = s.split("[^a-zA-Z]+")
```

Пример реализации:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Solution
{
    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z]+");

    private static void test(String s)
    {
        System.out.format("input string: '%s'\n", s);

        String[] words = pattern.split(s);
        //String[] words = s.split("[^a-zA-Z]+");

        // это уже необязательно - просто чтобы пустое слово не выводить как максимальное
        words = Stream.of(words).filter(v -> v.length() > 0).toArray(String[]::new);

        if ( words.length > 0 )
        {
            int max_len = words[0].length();
            int max_idx = 0;

            for ( int i = 1; i < words.length; ++i )
                if ( words[i].length() > max_len )
                {
                    max_len = words[i].length();
                    max_idx = i;
                }

            System.out.format("  the longest word is %d-th with length %d: '%s'\n", max_idx + 1, max_len, words[max_idx]);
        }
        else
            System.out.format("  no words found inside the string: '%s'\n", s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        test("");
        test("!@#$");
        test("single");
        test("@#_word_01_!?");
        test("__first, second; third...longest__'last'__////");
        test("3There 7has !been     9divided abs-      on98 then issue, with 578934 784,   +moderates5789 9concerned @about then on: then most vulnerable.");
    }
}
```

Comment: velial, спасибо за Ваш ответ. Я ещё не дошёл в изучении до регулярных выражений и паттернов. Буду стараться решить доступными мне способами. Но Ваш комментарий мне очень помог, спасибо.

Comment: velial, Объясните пожалуйста, почему здесь for ( int i = 1; i < words.length; ++i ) i равно единице, а не нулю ?

Comment: `for (int i = 1; ...)` был использован потому, что я уже использовал элемент с индексом 0 для инициализации: `max_len = words[0].length()`. Это просто способ избежать повторной обработки 0-го элемента массива

Comment: velial, ещё один вопрос. Вы можете мне объяснить, как отфильтровать массив words[], не используя регулярные выражения и стримы ? Мне для этого надо создать массив чаров и опять делать проверку на то, что в слове находятся только одни буквы ? Вот в этом моменте совсем не могу разобраться ((

Comment: Можете пройтись по массиву, проверяя каждое "слово" функцией isValidWord(), и если слово проходит проверку, сбрасывать его в коллекцию (например, ArrayList<String>). Потом вместо массива обрабатываете эту коллекцию, только не забудьте проверить кол-во элементов коллекции (она может и пустой оказаться, если не нашлось "правильных" слов)

Comment: velial, я должен использовать только массив ))) Тогда мне надо, если слово не прошло валидацию присваивать ему null , а прошедшие в новый массив записывать ?

Comment: Да, если нужно использовать  только массив, то Ваша идея присваивать null хороша, но я бы посоветовал присваивать пустую строку `""` - тогда не придётся в дальнейшем проверять элементы массива на null. Только не используйте для изменения массива цикл `for (String word : words)` - изменения в переменной `word` не будут отражаться в массиве, так что в данном случае нужен цикл `for (int i = 0; i<words.length(); i++)`.